# Random lines not being written from streamwriter C#

Tags: c#, file-io, streamwriter

I am currently working on fixing an issue with some legacy code. The code reads a csv, checks the data for validity, then writes the document to an outfile.

I am currently having difficulty determining the reason the process is being hung up. It is almost like it is stuck in an infinite loop. This issue happens on the same line every time (line 262). I have removed that line and it runs to line 1885 because getting hung up again. I continued to remove the lines that would causing issues into its on file and test that file. What is weird is that the errorLine file ran fine when it was just those in the file. This makes me think the issue must be coming from the streamwriter.

I have the streamwriter set to `autoFlush = true`. I am also using a `using` block so that should handle the `Flush/Close` of the streamwriter.

The files come in as a number of different sizes, some only a handful of rows and some as several thousand rows.

```
foreach (String e in fileNames)
                {

                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(e.Replace(inputDirectory, outputDirectory), false, Encoding.Unicode))
                    {
                        sw.AutoFlush = true;
                        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(e,Encoding.Unicode))
                        {
                            int peek = sr.Peek();
                            while (peek > -1) 
                            {
                                if (((char)peek).Equals(textQual)) 
                                        {
                                            sw.Write(((char)sr.Read()));
                                            peek = sr.Peek();
                                            if (((char)peek).Equals(textQual2))
                                            {
                                                sw.Write(((char)sr.Read())); 
                                                peek = sr.Peek();
                                                while (peek > 1)
                                                {
                                                    if (((char)peek).Equals((char)0x0A) || ((char)peek).Equals((char)0x0D)) 
                                                    {
                                                        check = false; 
                                                        row++;
                                                        if (firstcol == 0)
                                                        {
                                                            firstcol = col;
                                                        }
                                                        col = 0;

                                                        break;
                                                    }
                                                    else if (((char)peek).Equals(del)) 
                                                    {
                                                        check = false; 
                                                        break;
                                                    }
                                                    else if (((char)peek).Equals((char)0x22))
                                                    {
                                                        sr.Read();
                                                        doubleq++;
                                                    }

                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        sw.Write(((char)sr.Read()));
                                                        peek = sr.Peek();
                                                        break;
                                                    }
                                                }

                                            }
                            }
```

I am looking for any suggestions to this issue as I am not sure where this is coming from.

Comment: `This makes me think the issue must be coming from the streamwriter.` But this makes me think you have some problems in your code you haven't shown us.

Comment: I hope you are calling somewhere the "Next()" method since Peek only does is to give you the next character wihtout advancing in the reader!

Comment: I am reading character at a time.. When writing the file I am using sr.Read();

Comment: What you have posted won't even compile. You have got to create a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for anyone to be able to help you, and even for you to make any headway on this yourself.

Comment: @EZI I have made changes to this application and am certain it works. However the issue is coming from a particular file that came in. I have been debugging with that file as state above

Comment: @KevinMee So you are sure, its MS' bug not yours :)

Comment: Do they have anything in common? line 262 and 1885 I mean.

Comment: @EZI it almost certainly is a bug with me, However I am not sure how else to test this and am looking for suggestions. The program does work and completes for all test files I tested, however this particular files is causing issues on certain lines every time that I run the code

Comment: @ThomasLindvall Unfortunately there was nothing that I saw that was in common between those lines

Comment: @KevinMee Then where is **your code**? How do you parse the lines(most probably the bug is there). This lines `int peek = sr.Peek();
                            while (peek > -1)` doesn't mean much. Show your **real** code

Comment: @EZI I will post a modified version of my code as this contains client information.. Will update question in a moment

Answer (score 1):

you are in a infinite loop due to while (peek > -1) wich will always evaluate to true (if the strream contains at least one character).

Correct code would be something like this:

```
int peek = 0;
while ( (peek = sr.Peek ()) > -1) {
    char c = (char)peek;
   // doe whatever you want with picked character

    sr.Read ();


}
```

In my oppinion is very dangerous this code because there are cases when the while can run forever. For example, the if statement:

```
if (((char)peek).Equals(textQual))
```

Above, if the first character does not equal with textQual then the while will run forever. Not mentioning that it can happen with characters that are read further.

Above is clearly a piece of code that i wouldn't recommend to put it in production.

Comment: Right. I am in a loop to check the contains of the file and write out to a new file

Comment: @Kevin Mee Your while will run forever. Correct code would be: while ( (peek = sr.Peek ()) > -1) { // do some stuff and call  in the end sr.Read (); }

Comment: This is not the issue I am having. If this was the case all of my tests would have ended in an infinite loop.

Comment: @Kevin Mee From your new code example i can say maybe the line of code if (((char)peek).Equals(textQual))  returns always false. Anyway I would never recommend such a code to put in production. If the first character is not equal with textQual then the while runs forever

Comment: Why do you say it returns always false? The data is coming in with textQualifiers around each block of data

Comment: @Kevin Mee I said "maybe". Show me what are the values for textQual and textQual2

Comment: textQual is ~ textQual2 is * ... is the reason you said you wouldn't put this is prod because those were unknown?

Comment: I do include an if statement that handles characters that are not text qualifiers.